# Send email depending on success of curl command

Tags: bash, shell-script, email, curl

I created a script to monitor and have a query as below :-

```
httpUrl="http://some.website.ashx"
balExp=$(curl -v -X POST -d "UID=test&PWD=2222" $httpUrl)
```

How do I sent email alert (my email for example) if the query return nothing or times out?

**Update:**

I've modified the script to run the query

```
if [ $balExp -eq 0 ]
    echo "Success"
else 
    echo "failed"
fi
```

I always get failed but the `curl` command return success (0).

Comment: you can use the `mail` command. For example: `echo $balExp | mail me@mydomain.com -s "Subject Goes Here"`

Comment: how do I know if the query return success or nothing or time out...i just need to send email if the query return nothing or time out.

Comment: You can check the contents of `$balExp` and what the return code for the `curl` command is. `curl` will return non-zero on error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155923/sending-a-mail-from-a-linux-shell-script

Comment: The issue at hand is how your testing the error code. $balExp holds the value from curl stdout. Therefore unless this value is a integer equal to 0 the test fails. Shell scripts store the return code in $? from the most immediate executed instruction. Example: ` example.com; test [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "Success"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Curl exit code for failed HTTP requests

Usually if a requested HTTP resource isn’t available, a web server responds with a HTML document corresponding to the relevant HTTP status code, e.g. 404. In such cases, curl accepts this document from the server and since it was successful in getting a response from the web server, it displays the error document and exits with a status of 0 for success.

You want `curl` to return an error code if there was a problem retrieving the HTTP resource. For that, you need to provide the `-f, --fail` option to curl. From the curl man page:

> Fail silently (no output at all) on server errors. This is mostly done to better enable scripts etc to better deal with failed attempts. In normal cases when an HTTP server fails to deliver a document, it returns an HTML document stating so (which often also describes why and more). This flag will prevent curl from outputting that and return error 22.
>
> This method is not fail-safe and there are occasions where non-successful response codes will slip through, especially when authentication is involved (response codes 401 and 407).

*Note:* the above is (mostly) copied from my answer to [your similar question about curl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204762/return-code-for-curl-used-in-a-command-substitution/204790#204790).

#### Sending mail

You can use the `mail` program to send email. On Debian-based systems, it can
be installed via the `mailutils` package while on Red Hat-based distributions,
it’s provided by the `mailx` package.

```
echo "Body of email" | mail user@example.com -s "Subject line"
```

If you already use a command line mail client such as `mutt` you can use:

```
echo "Body of email" | mutt user@example.com -s "Subject line"
```

#### Testing the success of a command

When testing the output of a command you don’t need to use `test` or `[`. You can simply use the output of the command as in the following script (which incorporates all the above):

```
httpUrl="http://some.website.ashx"
if balExp=$(curl -f -v -X POST -d "UID=test&PWD=2222" "$httpUrl"); then
    echo "$balExp" | mail user@example.com -s "Successful download of $httpUrl"
else 
    echo "$balExp" | mail user@example.com -s "Problem downloading $httpUrl"
fi
```

Note that I've quoted the shell variable, `$httpUrl` using double-quotes so that the script will work with other URLs which may contain characters that are interpreted by the shell (`&` being a common one).

Finally, the `if` statement in your question was missing its corresponding `then`.

Comment: what if i want to run another curl, ive list of curl and need them to run 1by1 and print the output...do i use `count`.

Comment: @Asif In that case, I’d probably use a `for` loop. However, that would be [another question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts) so should be asked separately.