# Bash while loop stop after a successful curl request

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I'm currently learning how to write bash scripts. How do I stop while loop once I get a 200 response code on my curl request?

```
aws --endpoint-url http://s3.sample.com/ s3 cp hello.php s3://bucket/
while [ true ]
do
    curl http://sample.com/hello.php &> /dev/null
done
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The accepted answer to the [proposed duplicate target](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/204762/315749) shows how to make `curl` fail on any server error, returning `22` as its exit status. Based on that, you may write:

```bsh
until curl -s -f -o /dev/null "http://example.com/foo.html"
do
  sleep 5
done
```

Which reads "until `curl` successfully completes the requested transfer, wait 5 seconds and retry". `-f` makes `curl` fail on server errors, `-s` prevents it from printing messages and the progress meter, `-o /dev/null` assumes you are not interested in the content of the response.

However, `curl` is able to retry by itself, there is no need for a shell loop. For instance, to make it retry ten times and sleep five seconds before retrying:

```bsh
curl --retry 10 --retry-delay 5 -s -o /dev/null "http://example.com/foo.html"
```

Or, if you want it to retry even on non-transient HTTP errors (e.g. 404):

```bsh
curl --retry 10 -f --retry-all-errors --retry-delay 5 \
  -s -o /dev/null "http://example.com/foo.html"
```

If, instead, you are interested in running `curl` until the response shows a specific HTTP status:

```bsh
until [ \
  "$(curl -s -w '%{http_code}' -o /dev/null "http://example.com/foo.html")" \
  -eq 200 ]
do
  sleep 5
done
```

`-w` instructs `curl` to display the information specified by a format string (here, `%{http_code}`) after a completed transfer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the return code from curl in an if statement to then `exit` the loop.

```
while [ true ]
do
    curl http://sample.com/hello.php &> /dev/null
    if [[ "$?" -eq 0 ]]; then
        exit 0
    fi
done
```

If for some reason you wanted to continue in the script past the loop then you could use `break` instead of `exit`.

```
while [ true ]
do
    curl http://sample.com/hello.php &> /dev/null
    if [[ "$?" -eq 0 ]]; then
        break
    fi
done
echo "I made it out of the loop"
```

Comment: You can use just `if curl ...; then break; fi`  here, if you don't need the return value of `curl` for anything else. Also, in `while [ true ]`, the test checks if `true` is a non-empty string. It obviously is, so this does work in giving an endless loop. But `[ false ]` would also be always true, so a test like that is perhaps a bit misleading. Could use `while true; do` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but can you edit it to remove the invalid parenthesis ?